# ffmpeg audio to visualisation

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editor, audio

I would like to "convert" audio to video visualisation (oscilloscope or waveform) sort of like some media players have.

I read this thread on how to do so with ffmpeg: [How do I turn audio into video (that is, show the waveforms in a video)?](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/9644)

I have never used ffmpeg before and having read the previous thread I am still very confused with how to do it. As far as I know, ffmpeg does not have a GUI, so its a bit hard to understand.

I tried the following code:

```
ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]avectorscope=s=1080x1080,format=yuv420p[vid]" -map "[vid]" -map 0:a -codec:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset fast -codec:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 192k output.mp4
```

But the result i get is just a vertical line (the avectorscope does not spread out).

[image]

I have made sure that the audio is in stereo and has a high amplitude. I guess there is something I am missing in the code...

Also I would really like to know how I can change the background color from black to something custom.

Comment: Have you used a shell or, on Windows, the command line?

Comment: Can you provide your input file?

Comment: Not really because the content is private. It is a stereo MP3 file at 320kbps in 44.1 Hz

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/843774/create-a-video-file-from-an-audio-file-and-add-visualizations-from-audio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following command shows a video with a waveform of the corresponding audio:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x720,format=yuv420p[vid]" -map "[vid]" -map 0:a -codec:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset fast -codec:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 192k output.mp4
```

I replaced avectorscope with showwaves: avectorscope is for showing the difference between stereo pairs.
Try showcqt,showfreqs,showspectrum for other visualization effects.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you know any way to change the background from black to a custom color?

Comment: @Arete For what effect, specifically? Some, or at least showfreqs, already have alpha and you just need to overlay it over a color source. Otherwise you could try format filter and colorkey or chromakey filters.